# Как растягивать элементы ListBox на всю ширину (относительно ListBox )?

Tags: c#, wpf

Код:

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF54EC54" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
```

Даже при использовании `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` остаются вот такие неприятные отступы:

[image: Отступы]

Comment: Перепишите `ItemContainerStyle`, убрав у него отступы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, помогло